# How to switch Class nesting?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, subclass, nested

I've finally figured out how class deriving works, ... and it works completely opposite way I originally thought.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    Class5 A = new Class5();
    Class1 B = new Class1();
    void Start(){
        A.Function5(); // 5
        A.Function1(); // 1
        B.Function5(); // ERROR `Class1' does not contain a definition for `Function5' and no extension method `Function5' of type `Class1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        B.Function1(); // 1
    }
}

public class Class1{
    public void Function1(){
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
}
public class Class2 : Class1{
    public void Function2(){
        Debug.Log("2");
    }
}
public class Class3 : Class2{
    public void Function3(){
        Debug.Log("3");
    }
}
public class Class4 : Class3{
    public void Function4(){
        Debug.Log("4");
    }
}
public class Class5 : Class4{
    public void Function5(){
        Debug.Log("5");
    }
}
```

Q1 How Would I make in this Particular Code:

- not to be able to access Class 1, 2, 3, 4
- but can only access Class5 and THROUGH it access all other functions in other classes.

Q2 How would I make something like this:

```
public class Class5 : Class4, Class3, Class2, Class1{
    public void Function5(){
        Debug.Log("5");
    }
}
```

So that Class4 cannot read Class 3, ... **but** only Class 5 can read all other classes?

Comment: Prefer composition to inheritance.  It makes for a vastly more comprehensible dependency graph.  That said, if you need multiple inheritance in .Net, do it with interface rather than type inheritance.

Comment: wow what's an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `protected` on all `Function1..Function4` methods instead of `public` so only `Class5` can use functions 1-4...

Note that in C# class can have only one base class like `Class5:Class4 {}` (`Class5` will still see protected functions 1-4 of all its base classes ).

Comment: gr8 only thing that I'm missing now is how do I hide Class 1, 2, 3, 4 from public? THO I like if I call Class 1 I cannot access Func1